# Double integral limits under variable change with two new variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I can't seem to figure out how one would calculate the new limits for the following (general) case: $$I=\int_0^1dx_1\int^1_0dx_2f(x_1)f(x_2).$$
Suppose we do the variable change, $$M^2=x_1x_2S \ \ , Y=\frac{1}{2}log\left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right).$$
Where $S$ is a known constant. The Jacobian is $1/S$. We get,
$$I=\int dM^2\int dYf\left(\frac{M}{\sqrt{s}}e^Y\right)f\left(\frac{M}{\sqrt{s}}e^{-Y}\right)/S$$
because $x_1=\frac{M}{\sqrt{s}}e^Y$ and $x_2=\frac{M}{\sqrt{s}}e^{-Y}$.

**HOW DO I FIGURE OUT THE LIMITS OF $Y$?**

Because $Y$ depends on both $x_1$ and $x_2$ it seems to me that there is no definite way to do it.

Comment: I don't know if this can help, but you can try to evaluate the integral as follows: $$I(a)=\int_a^1dx_1\int^1_adx_2f(x_1)f(x_2),$$ where $a \in (0,1)$. Then, you can try to evaluate $$I = \lim_{a \to 0} I(a).$$